# UWP App performance degradation after usage - Windows 10

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using MVVM-Caliburn in my UWP application. There is a page where the user can add contacts on a form, and even increase the number of forms by clicking a button (the form is presented in a ListView, with multiple entries as per usage).

I have turned page caching as ENABLED.

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

The problem is that after a while, this particular page starts to slow down a lot and certain operations (even textbox input!) starts to take a lot of time.

Does this have to do with the fact that something gets cached and after a while, it starts to affect down the application performance?

Any help or direction in this matter will be welcomed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is where you locate a profiling tool and use it to investigate what's going on inside your application.

Comment: If you disable the navigation cache, does this issue still occur?

Comment: @Bite I tried that, that did help (to an extent) but disabling the cache means that the application will create a new page instance every time, and that increases memory usage.

Comment: @Will I ran a diagnostic session on VS 2015 (it just shows the RAM usage and the objects being created), did not find anything funny.

Comment: You need a diagnostic tool that can tell you what objects are in gen 2. That's where your issue will lie. I don't think VS does that for you.  I've used the ANTS profiler before, it worked well for me.